# C# Null Sockets

Tags: c#

When the socket is null, it lags everyone which is connected and I'm wondering what could be the cause of this, the affected code is below.

```
public void SendData(byte[] Data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Stopped)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (mSocket != null)
            {
                Output.WriteLine("[SND][" + mId + "]: " + Constants.DefaultEncoding.GetString(Data),
                    OutputLevel.DebugInformation);
                mSocket.BeginSend(Data, 0, Data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnDataSent), null);
            }
            else
            {
                using (SqlDatabaseClient MySqlClient = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
                {
                    Stop(MySqlClient);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           //SOCKETISNULL
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stop(MySqlClient); runs when the socket is null, not your catch block.  That's probably what's taking so long.

Comment: Don't ignore exceptions. You should display `e.ToString()` for troubleshooting purposes.